# iOS SDK: How to get a cell in a table view that is not visible?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How do I get the cell for an indexPath which is not currently visible in the table? (cell is out of range)

Code for getting my cell:

```
NSString *name = [[(ELCTextfieldCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] rightTextField] text];
```

`-cellForRowAtIndexPath...` returns `nil` because the cell at the required indexPath is out of range. So how do I get the correct cell and not nil?

Comment: Please provide more info and code.

Comment: OK, I have a grouped table view, where some cells have textfields and at the end there are cells that represents buttons.
Now I have the problem that if I am at the end of the table view my first couple of cells is now out of range but if I click on a cell that represents a button, I need the information provided at the beginning.
Now I tried: [[(ELCTextfieldCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] rightTextField] text] but -cellForRowAtIndexPath:... returns nil because the cell is out of range.
So, how do I get the correct cell (and not nil)?

Comment: The answer to your question is as nacho4d says - don't use the cells to get the information, get it from your underlying data source. The broader answer is that you seem to be using a table view to lay out a scrolling UI instead of using a view in a scroller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how it works. You need to grab and store the information as soon as it is entered or changed. It may easily get out of scope and you cannot guarantee your cell lives long enough. Well, technically you can hold onto it (and always return the very same cell for the same index path), but I'd question that design.

Comment: OK, but I have a table where cells can be added dynamically and I don't know how many cells the user will produce.

Comment: I think the only reasonable approach is to save the changes as soon as they happen. You may have a hard time retrieving that data later, and the cell might even be already "dead" and freed.

Answer (score 17):

The `UITableView` only keeps the visible cells. If you need one that isn't visible you have to call the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the `UITableView` `dataSource`. So, if self is a class that is the `dataSource`:

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [self tableView:table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: In general that won't preserve data that was entered in those cells. Only works if still in cache.

Answer (score 2):

UITableViewCells are made to be reused/recycled in a way that the users won't need to create more cells than the number of visible ones.
You usually don't need to access a cell that is not visible. It should be enough you access your datasource and get/set the correspondent data there. Cells are for showing some state of the datasource. Not the datasource itself :)

**Edit:**

You said you need some information (text) from one cell above, right? If you use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method the cell will be recreated but you might not get the text that was in the textfield. The reason? because probably you didn't save it somewhere else. If you did save it, then access that directly instead of going through the cell.

Answer (score 1):

In continue to @Raphael's answer, Here is the (working) **swift 3** solution:

`UITableViewCell cell = self.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)`

Answer (score 0):

Is the information to fill your table coming from an array? Could you not pull that directly out of the array at 0 index, same as your cellForRowAtIndexPath would presumably retrieve and fill that cell when it is displayed?